# Programatically modify android Spinner child views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

Using the latest Android API (19 at the time of this post), I'm trying to get the various children of a basic Spinner as TextViews.

In my fragment's `onCreateView` method I've got a reference to the spinner:

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_spinner);
```

(which looks something like this in the Fragment):

```
<Spinner android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/icon_spinner"
         android:layout_below="@+id/button_check_in"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
         android:spinnerMode="dialog"
         android:entries="@array/marker_names" />
```

However, calling `spinner.getChildCount()` in the fragment's `onCreateView` returns `0`. The spinners Adapter is populated with values, and the spinner works fine in the app, so the children views must be populated at some later time.

*When am I able to get the child views for a spinner, or how can I do so if I'm going about this wrong?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the docs more I realized that spinners do not store their child views directly. Instead, they must be accessed through the `SpinnerAdapter`'s `getDropDownView` method.

eg.

```
spinner.getAdapter().getDropDownView(id, null, null);
```